# css image box with horizontal line on the right

Tags: html, css

After searching around for a few hours, I hope someone can help me with this case.

I want to achieve this effect on multiple images across a post. The HTML content is already created, and I can't modify or add an element to it. I can only play with CSS.

[image: box with a horizontal line]

**Problem** : Each image have different height size, meaning height can change depend on the image. Do I need to use the calc property?

```css
figure.size-full {
  border: 2px solid #bcc6b4;
  padding: 0;
  }

.wp-block-image img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.wp-block-image figcaption {
  margin-top: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-style: italic;
}

figure.wp-block-image:before{
width: 2000px;
height: 1px;
background-color: #bcc6b4;
display: block;
content: "";
position: relative;
top: 32px;
right: -100%;
z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full">
<img loading="lazy" src="vitamineA.jpg" alt="test image" class="wp-image-34340" >
<figcaption>Aliments riches en vitamine A</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: How many images do you have? How do you want to align them like?

Comment: It will depend of the post. Each image has a different height, that's why I don't know how to center horizontally the line in css depending on the variable height of the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try css flex. If it doesn't work as expected, increase the selector weight or make the properties as important.

```
figure.wp-block-image {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```